# How to retrieve text from Android support library action bar SearchView?

Tags: android, android-support-library, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the Android compat support library for the action bar search view. How can I add an event that triggers when I click the search button on the keyboard after typing something?

So far I have this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_users, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

The [Google docs page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) doesn't seem to tell me this, it only shows how to set it up...
So far I can see the search icon, and when I click it, it reveals the `EditText`, and I can type into it, and then if I click the search button on the keyboard nothing happens. I want to then trigger an event that can get that string so I can do what I want with it.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `QueryTextListener`:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO : query is the text from the search view 
        // after you clicked search
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO : newText is the text from the search view 
        // (event triggered every time the text changes)
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at the documentation of the SearchView.

You can set hints for the user, get the query,... and at the same time listeners to be notified when something "interesting" happens.

[Documentation for SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)